# Q: 'UnboundLocalError': local variable 'exitErr' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, testing, package, spyder, fipy

I want to use the PDE Solver Fipy in the Spyder IDE and tried installing it according to the official installation guide:
Now it is suggested to run fipy.test() before using the package and here the following error appeared.

```
File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\fipy\tests\test.py", line 263, in run_tests
    raise exitErr

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'exitErr' referenced before assignment
```

I do not understand what this means in this context, here is the code that this Error is referring to:

```
    try:
        unittest.main(
            None, None, [unittest.__file__]+self.test_args,
            testLoader = loader_class()
            )
    except SystemExit as exitErr:
        # unittest.main(..., exit=...) not available until Python 2.7
        from fipy.tests.doctestPlus import report_skips
        report_skips()
        if self.timetests is not None:
            pass
        else:
            raise

    if "legacy" in printoptions:
        numerix.set_printoptions(legacy=printoptions["legacy"])

    if self.timetests is not None:
        from fipy.tests.doctestPlus import _DocTestTimes
        import numpy
        _DocTestTimes = numpy.rec.fromrecords(_DocTestTimes, formats='f8,S255', names='time,test')
        _DocTestTimes.sort(order=('time', 'test'))
        numpy.savetxt(self.timetests, _DocTestTimes[::-1], fmt="%8.4f\t%s")

    raise exitErr
```

Comment: "exitErr" wasn't set yet when "raise exitErr" was executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. I've filed an issue.

I believe you can fix this error by changing the relevant code in `fipy.tests.test.test.run_tests()` to read:

```py
exitErr = None
try:
   ...
except SystemExit, exitErr:
  ...

...

if exitErr is not None:
   raise exitErr
```

but I need to do some tests. I can't actually trigger the error you see, but our code you've identified is definitely wrong.